# Only build feature/* branches

Tags: git, teamcity

I am trying to setup a TeamCity build to only build feature branches, and ignore master, develop, etc.

I current have this in this in my Branch specification:

+:refs/heads/feature/*

Answer (score 13):

The following setup is working for my pre-release builds on TeamCity 8.0.6.

Branch specification (visible when you select "Show Advanced Settings"):

```
+:refs/heads/hotfix/(*)
+:refs/heads/release/(*)
```

Default branch: `teamcity-default-dummy`

From my understanding you need to specify a default branch other than the branch you want to exclude. I believe it will trigger on commits to the default branch, regardless of branch specification, but I may be wrong.

I had to create a dummy branch and point default here for my pre-release build configuration, because I just got an error it could not get changes from master branch, which does not exist in my repo. You might not need to do this.

Related, I found [this article](http://www.tigranetworks.co.uk/blogs/electricdreams/ci-build-with-teamcity-git-and-gitflow-workflow/) very useful for setting up git with TeamCity. Although this focuses on git-flow the same concepts apply for any branching model.

**Update Feb 2015**

Still as of TeamCity 9.0 you need to specify a default branch and the default branch will trigger builds. For this case I recommend creating a dummy branch that will never be committed to, such as in the example above.

Help upvote on: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-24147

Comment: From my experience Teamcity will always trigger on commits to the default branch, even if you put a branch spec of `-:refs/heads/whatever-your-default-is`. Disappointing, if you ask me.

Comment: This question is 2 years old, still this hasn't been fixed! Default branch just doesn't work well with Git Flow, because most of the time you have feature/* or release/* branches. We're running TeamCity 9.0 and have to set a default branch. And if the build fails on the default branch, but succeeds on latest release/* branches, the project is marked as failed. See here: http://i.imgur.com/uxefDWb.png

Comment: @Gaui I've seen tickets in their issue tracker I'm sure you can help upvote. That said, the workaround in this answer has worked flawlessly for us for about a year now so to me it's more of a nuisance than a problem.

Comment: This seems to be the main ticket in their issue tracker for upvoting: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-24147

Comment: @DaveZych: According to recent comments in the linked issue, it's possible to exclude the default branch from automatic triggering, but you will still get the ever growing pending changes list.

Comment: do you need the parenthesis around the asterix?

Comment: @tofutim: No, parentheses are used for naming purposes only.

Answer (score 3):

At this time this is not possible. You have to define a default branch. TeamCity takes it into account when it calculates changes in the build in the feature branch and in many other places. As a workaround you can modify your build script to do something different when it is run on a default branch.